# Why is my keyboard mapping wrong with Xming, Lubuntu in VirtualBox and Putty?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, putty, xorg, lubuntu

I am running **Lubuntu** in a **VirtualBox** guest on a **Windows 7** host.

I have started the X server **XMing** on the host.

I use **Putty** with X-forwarding to **ssh** into the guest and use it to start **lxterminal**.

This works pretty well except that my Swedish keyboard presses are not coming across correctly. The effect is that I seem to be using a US keyboard although I am not. E.g. when I press 'ö', ';' appears in the terminal. The same happens in xterm too.

Running this in the lxterminal:

`$ setxkbmap -v 10 -query`

Produces:

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Applied rules from xorg:
rules:      xorg
model:      pc105
layout:     se
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   xfree86+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+se+inet(pc105)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
rules:      xorg
model:      pc105
layout:     se
```

So it seems that the layout is set correctly. Right?

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an option called "Additional parameters for Xming" in configuration of Xming/XLaunch. If you pass something like

```
-xkbmodel pc105 -xkblayout us,se -xkboptions grp:ctrl_shift_toggle
```

You will have the same effect as in solution from Peter but without using any other programs.
Found solution here: http://my.opera.com/paintenzero/blog/xmi

Comment: Thanks! I will try it out as soon as possible, since my solution has a problem: I need to rerun it quite frequently.

Comment: Turns out this solves the issue for me, if I just use "-xkblayout fi" (fi is Finnish, se won't work, don't ask me why). According to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/console-setup/+bug/35611 Swedish and Finnish keyboard layouts do not differ at all.

Comment: I also managed to get it working when specifying `-xkblayout fi`. Weird that Swedish keyboard layout doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it myself. By chance I discovered the command **lxkeymap**. It seems to be the same dialog that is used to select keymap when installing Lubuntu. In it, *Sweden* was selected, but *Swedish* was not, so I selected that and pressed *Apply*. Now it works as it should!